# Bison not parsing multiple lines?

Tags: c++, c, bison, yacc, lex

I'm writing a C parser using Bison. My parser's .y file, when watered down VERY much, looks a bit like this:

```
%parse-param {YYSTYPE *root} /* Used to detect the statement/declaration type, and print the tokens back out again */
/* Tokens defined here, etc */
%start program

program : decl { *root = $1; } | 
          decl program { *root = $1; }
;

decl : INTEGER_TOKEN identifier SEMICOLON 
;
```

This all works okay when you do for example "int x;" but if I want to do "int x; int y" then it will ignore the second line, and pretend I only inputted "int x;"

Is there some special way that you need to handle multiple lines of input? Any suggestions you have would be appreciated.

Comment: do you treat linefeeds like spaces in your lexer?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I basically check for this regex in my lexer: `\r?\n yyextra = 1;` When it's found, I just set yyextra to 1;

Comment: you mean it ignores `int x; int y` when on separate lines or whatever?

Comment: It doesn't ignore int x; it just ignores int y; - It doesn't even need to be separate lines. It can just be a space.

Comment: How do you know? The parser doesn't do anything observable from the outside.

Comment: When I get to a decl, I create a node and store some information in it. Then I print that node out again. It should be creating 2 nodes. It's not, though

Comment: There is about a zillion ways to implement what you've just described *wrong*.  [mcve] please.

Comment: Actually, there are only 47. I checked.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the point of setting `yyextra = 1`? How can that information be used by the parser?

Comment: It's not. It's used in the lexer.

Comment: @ColonelHedgehog: You probably don't need `yyextra` for that. You can just use a local variable, assuming that it is not used *after* the next token is actually returned.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what your program actually does but the reduced program will certainly ignore all but the first decl. Consider:

```
program : decl { *root = $1; } | 
          decl program { *root = $1; }
;
```

Since this rule is right-recursive (which is likely not what you want) it will effectively execute the actions `*root = $1;` from right to left. That is, the first assignment to `*root` will be the last declaration, and subsequently executed actions (corresponding to successively previous declarations) will overwrite that value. The last action executed corresponds to the first declaration, which will be the final value placed into `*root`.

Why do the actions execute right-to-left? Because actions are executed at the end of the matched string. An action corresponding to `program: decl program` will execute after the second non-terminal `program` has been recognised, which means that the inner `program`'s action will already have been executed. Since the action for `program` is really dealing with the `decl`, that means that the `decl`s are dealt with backwards. If you used normal left-recursion (`program : program decl`), the the inner `program` will be executed first, so the `decl`s will be handled left-to-right.

Comment: I do think you're on to something. So basically my rule looks like this:

```program
  : decl { *root = $1; } |
    program decl { *root = $1; }
;```

But *root still is assigned to the first decl, but it won't assign to then next decl after parsing the first. If I set it so the SECOND rule assigns *root to $2, then it will only set *root to the LAST decl. In the example I provided in my initial question, that'd be "int y"

Comment: @ColonelHedgehog: Well, yes. That's fairly obvious, no? *root only has room for one value; the normal rules of physics (or, at least, of C) apply. If you want it to be a list of declarations, you'll need to make it a different datatype.

Comment: Yeah but it's not like it sets to its value after all the parsing is done. Each time it reaches one of the program arguments it should be reassigned, then all the handling will happen.

Comment: @ColonelHedgehog: Where does the "handling happen"? If it is when yyparse returns, then what makes you think yyparse will return at that point?